# BitBucket - what's the catch? (TANSTAAFL, right?)

Tags: version-control

The BitBucket capabilities, and pricing (up to 5 users for free) left me wondering what the catch was... there is no such thing as a free lunch, after all.

What is BitBucket getting out of my unpaid participation, besides a handsome man to freely include in their promotional materials (per the TOS)?

Comment: You can always fish ...

Comment: This is also called the [freemium model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium).

Comment: What they get out of me: 1) a few bug reports, 2) I'm always suggesting bitbucket to friends and colleagues (and numerous times on this site, on related questions), 3) I'm now a paying customer (after being extremely satisfied as a non paying one)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the same profit model that people have been using for years, since the rash of free anti-virus software for individuals.

Basically, you will get used to using BitBucket, and when there comes a time that you are working at a company who needs a service like BitBucket, you will go straight there rather than evaluating the alternatives. Then they will make money from your participation.

Comment: so they want to hook me as a private user, and then hope I lobby for adoption of their service by my employer?

Comment: @AndrewHeath: Yes. Such models have proven effective in software sales; there is no reason it shouldn't work in service provision. There is a higher risk though, because in software it costs you no more to provide a free version, while if you have nothing but non-paying users of a service then it becomes expensive. But then there is always the Wikipedia approach of saying "if you want us to continue, then we need $X in donations."

Answer (score 18):

[@bitbucket](http://twitter.com/#!/bitbucket) answered this a few times. To put it short, pretty much they like to make their income off businesses and teams who can afford it. Free users are not costing them *that much*, and when the time comes, a once time single user who upgraded to a team, which needs more serious support, will probably upgrade to a paid account as well. After all, IMHO, their prices are pretty reasonable.

Comment: I'm located in a socially harmonious country that protects me from conduits of capitalist filth and propaganda like Twitter, so I apologize if I missed an oft-discussed issue on their feed.

Comment: @AndrewHeath - same here, except the twitter propaganda :)))

Comment: @AndrewHeath - Sorry about that ;) Seriously, if you plan on using BitBucket their tw. account is a wonderful source of information. The crew is also really helpful if you have a problem with a particular feature at any point. I haven't had any, but have seen particular quircks solved in a matter of minutes. Don't know about you, but I always value helpful chaps more than any feature in a service.

Comment: @Idigas - I've added their blog to my aggregator. I'll make a note to fire up the VPN and check their twitter feed once a week or so. thanks :-)

Comment: @AndrewHeath That's irony right?

Comment: @Tivie - not at all. Twitter has been *harmonized* (is not available without VPN).

Comment: @AndrewHeath I didn't know that twitter was censored

Comment: @Tivie - Twitter has been blocked in the PRC since 2009 or so. Same with Facebook and YouTube and a variety of other similar sites.

Answer (score 3):

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) works well with other services like [Atlassian Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview) (CI) and [Atlassian Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview/) which are a paid services.

Comment: Thanks for making your first Stack Exchange Programmers post.